# By Default to set Enable Spell Check in Ckeditor (SCAYT)

Tags: javascript, php, plugins, ckeditor

I'm using SCAYT plugin for CKEditor. I need to enable scayt automatically on startup. I have already tried this code

```
config.scayt_autoStartup = true;
```

But it doesn't work for my browser. please guide me!

Answer (score 1):

By default, browser native spell check functionality is disabled in the editor. Use the CKEDITOR.config.disableNativeSpellChecker configuration option to enable it:

config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false;

Comment: Rajkumar this code can i apply with config.js i am right ?

Comment: omg ! not working when i set this code config.scayt_autoStartup = true; it seems like works in internet explorer spell checker (SCAYT) set by default. other browsers(Mozilla and Chrome ) will not work

Answer (score 0):

If the question is still actual for you. Using config.scayt_autoStartup = true; in CKEditor config.js file is a correct way to make SCAYT start on the page load. It works properly in IE8+, MS Edge, Chrome, FF, Safari.

If it still doesn't work, check if you are passing a correct CKEditor config.js file on your web page with CKEDitor, as this might be a reason why the parameter doesn't work.